# Attribute Error for Python Class, but is declared

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object, attributes

I am getting an attribute error for one of my python class, but I declared it in the init function for the class. I do not know what I am doing wrong

[image: I am getting an attribute error for one of my python class, but I declared it in the init function for the class. I do not know what I am doing wrong]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You spelt "`__init__`" wrongly as "`__int__`"

Comment: Oh my god! Thank you!

Comment: Please accept my answer if it was helpful! :) We both get reputation haha